# Dependent texts field not rerendering in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I have two dependent fields in the visualforce page. One is a picklist and text field. So based on the stage the picklist fields works but not the values of text field is not refreshing the value

```
 <input type="hidden" id="oppId" value="{!opp1.Id}"></input>
                                <apex:outputLabel value="Stage Name" for="statusPicklist"/>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!opp1.StageName}" id="statusPicklist" required="false" styleClass="slds-select"/>
                                <apex:outputLabel value="CPP Status Reason" for="statusReason"/>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!opp1.CPP_Status_Stage_Reason__c}" id="statusReason" required="false" styleClass="slds-select"/>
                                <apex:outputLabel value="Probability" for="probability"></apex:outputLabel>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!opp1.Probability}" id="probability" required="false" styleClass="slds-input"/>
```

Comment: not sure, what you mean by a dependent text field, did you implement a validation rule like [described here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h002AAA)?

Comment: Actually the field is Proability and it is not a dependent field. I query the proability based on stage and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Actually the field is Proability and it is not a dependent field. I query the proability based on stage and fixed it